# Can I share the /uploads/ folder between multiple WordPress servers?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress blog which is replicated, i.e. 2 servers behind load balancer serve the same wordpress blog. I pointed the database on both servers to the same database so I have no problem there. However, when a user is forwarded (by the load balancer) to server-1 and uploads files, they are kept on server-1. The same goes for server-2. Those files are not shared between the 2 servers and therefore user who is forwarded to server-2 will not see the files (e.g. images) which were uploaded to server-1.

I read that the upload folder can be changed but "This path can not be absolute. It is always relative to ABSPATH".

What are the best practices to share the upload folder between servers?

Comment: i know it's possible to "symlink" directories using SSHFS. never tried it myself unfortunately

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29273/is-it-possible-to-share-wordpress-media-files-among-different-domains

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/340911/how-to-share-uploads-directory-with-another-site-on-the-same-server

Answer (score 2):

Options:

1. Set something up to replicate files between servers. ie: rsync in a cron job
2. Mount a network share to the uploads folder on both servers.

Comment: [GlusterFS](http://www.gluster.org/about/) is ideal for this kind of network share

Comment: @BenLanc GlusterFS is a little much to simply share one folder between two servers.

Comment: sure, but it's very tolerant if one goes down as there is no "master" per se. Defeats the point in load balancing two servers if there's a single point of failure

Comment: how can I set a network share if I have to specify a path which is relative to the ABSPATH?

Answer (score 2):

You are already load balancing, why not get rid of some of the http load.
Move the uploads to something like s3 
Here is one plugin for it http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp2cloud-wordpress-to-cloud/

Moving the rest of your static files, eg. theme & plugin files would also be good for the server load.

Comment: Assuming there is a plug-in which needs image available locally for cropping; how do you synchronize uploads folder among different production nodes ?

Comment: Most of plugins I worked with won't work with multiple nodes behind load balancer. They just assume that even if you use some media offload, you're still have those files in your local uploads folder.